# Arithmetic/Logical operations with long long data type 

Tags: c

Given `long long int x, y;`, I want a function that can compare x & y and returns T/F Flag, which is a normal int 32-bit. I tried this, but it confused me

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 long long n,i;

 scanf("%l64d", &n);
 i=42;

 printf("%l64d", n);
 printf("%l64d", i);
 printf("\ni<=n --> %d\n",i<=n);
 return;
```

}

Comment: Arthimatic?  Arithmetic?  Arthritic?  Are you talking about bitwise or logical ops?  `&` is bitwise

Comment: @Catcall Sorry, I couldn't  put my code I tried. Some how I got confused. But I am not lazy in trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you are seeking is exemplified by this (which returns true/1 or false/0 depending on whether `x` is greater than (gt) `y`):

```
int ll_compare_gt(long long x, long long y)
{
    return(x > y);
}
```

Repeat for the other comparisons...

Arithmetic is more problematic - often, the result of adding two `long long` values is too big to fit into a 32-bit `int`.

However, your question is very sketchy on details and this might be quite wide of the mark.  You should explain what you really want much more clearly.

Comment: Not mention if you just want to compare (not to pass the function around), you can just write `x > y` without having to use the function!

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks your code is working. I am trying to understand the concept porting of OS(Linux). Thanks all